# React json form schema- To remove fields in onChange

Tags: reactjs, react-jsonschema-forms

How to remove some fields, depends on the input I got for a field (in onChange) in react json form schema.

I have used readOnly=true. It doesn't work

For example: If I get eventprocessingeventcomstatusidid as 1, need to remove this field 'eventprocessingeventcostidid' from my form.

const changingSchema = (formData, p) => {
if (formData.formData.eventprocessingeventcomstatusidid == 1) {
eventProcessingFormSchema.properties.eventprocessingeventcostidid.readOnly = true;
setEventProcessingUIFormSchema(eventProcessingUIFormSchema);
}

I tried this way,it doesn't change into readOnly quickly. After I gave input,it will change into readonly format